# Swing MigLayout - can't avoid unnecessary gap

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I'm writing some Swing application for surveying purposes using `MigLayout`. I'm trying to remove unnecessary gap.

I've already noticed that the gap is present because of the sentence at the top. When I remove it, however, it looks fine.

The issue is visible on the following picture:

[image]

The way I add the sentence is:

```
add(text, "wrap, center, gap top 20");
```

And the way I add buttons:

```
String wrap = shouldWrap(i) ? "wrap" : "";
this.add(button, "gapbefore 15, width 50, height 20, " + wrap);
```

Can anyone please help me with explaining why it's happening and how I can remove the gap with the sentence present?

////////////EDIT

I wanted to work with my current infrastucture, I've enabled debug mode in `MigLayout` and I see something like this:

[image: My JPanel in debug mode looks like this]

I'm wondering why border's size around every first component in a row is set to match the "Please, specify how much you agree with the given statements" sentence's size.

Is there any way to disable that option for every component using `MigLayout`?

Comment: What component is the rectangular gray objects with rounded corners? They seem well suited to using a `JRadioButton` (in a `ButtonGroup`). Since each radio button includes a 'check box' and string, it would then suggest a `GridLayout` for positioning the radio buttons.

Comment: The rectangular grey objects are JToggleButtons, each 7 buttons in a row are grouped in a ButtonGroup. I'll try out to work with some aditionnal layouts, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use the constraing "split x", which will divide the row into X parts that are huddled together:

**Without split:**

```
public class SentenceExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());

        panel.add(new JLabel("Please, specify how much you agree with the given statements"), "wrap");

        panel.add(new JButton("1"));
        panel.add(new JButton("2"));
        panel.add(new JButton("3"));
        panel.add(new JButton("4"));
        panel.add(new JButton("5"));
        panel.add(new JButton("6"));
        panel.add(new JButton("7"));
        panel.add(new JButton("8"));
        panel.add(new JButton("9"));
        panel.add(new JButton("10"));

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(900, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This looks like this:

[image: WithoutSplit]

**With split:**

If you change the first JButton-line from this:

```
panel.add(new JButton("1"));
```

to this:

```
panel.add(new JButton("1"), "split 10");
```

your GUI will look like this:

[image: WithSplit]

The first button with the constraint "split 10" arranges 10 "slots", where the button itself and the next 9 elements will be put into.

Do this for the first button in every row (i.e. with a loop) and you have the look you wanted.

---

**Edit:** 
If using a loop for every first button is too cumbersome, you can use the column constraints for the panel-layout itself, by making it have i.e. 7 columns and make the sentence span over several columns. See here http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf for how to create column constraints.

"split" might be easier to use, but the column constraints might be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks m8, thats a great answer! But Ive found my own solution yesterday's morning. I will describe it below.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply nest JPanels and use a compound layout?

For instance, the overall JPanel could use a BorderLayout with the JLabel title at the top (BorderLayout.PAGE_START possition), and an inner JPanel could use MigLayout, hold the grid of components, and be held in the outer JPanel's BorderLayout.CENTER position.